# R-squared unbiased when F-test is biased in heteroscedasticity?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, bias, r-squared, f-test

If R2 and F-statistic are in functional relationship, is it possible, that in case of heteroscedasticity F-test is biased but R-squared is not?

Comment: Do you really talk about the bias of a statistical test?

Comment: I'm talking about wrong distribution of F statistic in case of heteroskedasticity.

Comment: Bias means $E(\hat \theta)-\theta \ne 0$. What does your bias mean?

Comment: For $R^2$ to be biased, we have to have a sense of what it estimates. Particularly when the errors lack a common variance, what would that be?